# LESS syntax coloring breaks in upgrade to Sublime Text 3 build 3065

Tags: less, sublimetext3

My LESS syntax broke on upgrade my sublime text 3 to the latest release.

I installed the LESS package and I received an error after the upgrade mentioning that it could not pick up the LESS syntax (unfortunately I can't replicate the error).

I can set the language to CSS and it's ok, but not ideal. Anyone run into this problem?

Comment: This isn't the kind of question for StackOverflow, you should post your issue to Sublime's support or forum. http://www.sublimetext.com/support http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by:

1. Removing the LESS package
2. Re-installing the LESS package
3. Closing Sublime Text
4. Re-opening Sublime Text
5. Opening a .less file
6. Switching the syntax back to LESS

Voila! Less *IS* more!

Comment: Tried all of the above. Still fails to load for me :/ I have to set the syntax manually every time I open a *.less file.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem currently after updating sublime text 4 to build 4143. Looking for a solution I scrolled through the setting files and found (on mac):

~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings

… and in it:

```
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Less",
```

Deleting the line with "Less" in it solved the problem.